# Pairing with itertools combinations - long code execution on large volume of data

Tags: python, combinations

I am working on a task to get all possible combinations (pairs) of ID's (companies) which paritipated in one bid and create a new data frame with ID_1, ID_2, matching parameter (tender ID).

I have prepared the following two functions which provide me with the required result however the execution time exceeds several hours when applying to df with more than 500k lines.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
```

```
def get_pairs(dataframe, items):
   return (
       (c1, c2, item)
       for item in items
       for c1, c2 in combinations(dataframe[dataframe['tender_product'] == item]['ID_name'], 2)
   )
```

```
def get_all_pairs(df):
        pairs = get_pairs(df,df['tender_product'])
        df= pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['ID_name1', 'ID_name2','tender_product'])
        df=df.query('ID_name1 != ID_name2')
        df=df.drop_duplicates()
        df['pair'] = df['ID_name1'].astype(str)+'_'+df['ID_name2'].astype(str)
        df['reversed_pair'] =df['ID_name1'].astype(str)+'_'+df['ID_name2'].astype(str)
        return df
```

What are the options to optimize the code to make it work faster with the same result?

The sample of intial data:

| ID | tender_product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tender_1 |
| 2 | tender_1 |
| 3 | tender_2 |
| 4 | tender_2 |

The sample of current output:

| ID1 | ID2 | tender_product | pair | reversed_pair |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | tender_1 | 1_2 | 2_1 |
| 3 | 4 | tender_2 | 3_4 | 4_3 |

Comment: This seems better suited for the Code Review site.

Comment: Also would be good to include a few lines of data with expected output.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired outcome here is but if I understand it, your method seems ill-advised. If you have a large number of companies/ID's your potentially creating a ludicrously wide dataset. Nor is it obvious that in a real world scenario you'd only ever have two bidding companies/ids for a single tender, as in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on how efficient this would be (I don't have the 500K lines to test! :) )
But this should do what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        'tender_product': ['tender_1', 'tender_1', 'tender_2', 'tender_2', 'tender_3', 'tender_3', 'tender_4', 'tender_4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_df = df.groupby('tender_product')['ID'].apply(list).reset_index() #Group by tender product and send matching IDs to a list stored in the result column
new_df.rename(columns={'ID': 'ID1'}, inplace=True) #Rename column to ID1
new_df['ID2'] = new_df['ID1'].apply(lambda x: x[1]) #Extract value from list at position 1 (second value in list)
new_df['ID1'] = new_df['ID1'].apply(lambda x: x[0]) #Extract value fromlist at position 0 (first value in list)
```

#Note: The order is important here. If we replace the ID1 value first, the list held in that cell will cease to exist because we've replaced it

Finally, we create the combination of IDs in two new columns

```
new_df['pair'] = new_df.apply(lambda row: f"{row['ID1']}_{row['ID2']}", axis=1)
new_df['reversed_pair'] = new_df.apply(lambda row: f"{row['ID2']}_{row['ID1']}", axis=1)
```

Tested in Jupyter:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses!
First of all I understood that items used were not optimal, changed to .unique(). Further applied group.by() as follows

```
def get_pairs(dataframe:pd.DataFrame,items:list):
num = len(items)
pairs = []

# grouping
dat_gr = dataframe.groupby(['tender_product'])

# cur - progress tracker
# item - current item
# dat_df - data for the item
for cur,(item,dat_df) in enumerate(dat_gr,1):
    prc = cur / num; print(f"Текущий прогресс: {cur} из {num} ({prc:0.0%})", item)

    # Series with IDs 
    cmp_sr = dat_df['ID']        
    if len(cmp_sr) > 1:
        pairs.extend( (str(c1), str(c2), item) for c1, c2 in combinations(cmp_sr.tolist(), 2) )

return pairs
```